# How do I tell Jekyll/Maruku which post has the Markdown syntax error?

Tags: jekyll, maruku

How do I tell Jekyll/Maruku to tell me which file has my Mardown syntax error?

The build warning only tells me so much:

```
$ jekyll --safe

Configuration from /homne/me/_config.yml
Building site: /homne/me -> /homne/me/_site

 ___________________________________________________________________________
| Maruku tells you:
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Could not find ref_id = "md_entityhellip" for md_link([md_entity("hellip")],"md_entityhellip")
| Available refs are ["png", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------
!/home/eoin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/maruku-0.6.1/lib/maruku/errors_management.rb:49:in `maruku_error'
!/home/eoin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/maruku-0.6.1/lib/maruku/output/to_html.rb:716:in `to_html_link'
!/home/eoin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/maruku-0.6.1/lib/maruku/output/to_html.rb:970:in `block in array_to_html'
!/home/eoin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/maruku-0.6.1/lib/maruku/output/to_html.rb:961:in `each'
!/home/eoin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/maruku-0.6.1/lib/maruku/output/to_html.rb:961:in `array_to_html'
\___________________________________________________________________________
Not creating a link for ref_id = "md_entityhellip".Successfully generated site: /homne/me -> /homne/me/_site
```

Comment: What version of jekyll are you running?

Comment: Jekyll version 0.12.0

Comment: I've had similar problems. They made the error reporting better in the newer version. I would try to use the newest commit of Jekyll and see if it gives you better error messages.

Comment: Nice, sounds like the answer, thanks.

Comment: for future users, updating to Jeykll 1.2.0 solved the issue for me.

Comment: running 1.4.3 and happening

Comment: @DirtyHenry running 1.4.2 still happening

Answer (score 0):

The next version of Jekyll will have better error reporting with MaRuKu and include the path to the file that caused the error.

The current [master branch](http://github.com/mojombo/jekyll) on GitHub should be stable enough that you could use it for testing purposes. Feedback would be welcome if you do decide to test it out. Thanks!